# Can not read Firestore DB from custom npm package using Firestore object passed from application

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write my own npm package that uses Firestore database.
I initialize class from package with Firestore object that I pass from application:

```
import { firestoreTest } from 'my-package'

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(app)
const test = new firestoreTest(db)
```

When I call function from my package `await test.getDoc('pathto/doc')` I get error:
`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore`

I tried different combinations of initialising Firestore object that is used to read from Firestore.
Only case when I can read from Firestore is only when I fully initialize Firebase app in my package using `firebaseConfig`, but then I don't inherit authentication from parent app can only read publicly accessible collections.

I have even tried to pass `doc(db, documentPath)` to package and then I got error that give me a hint of what could be happening: `Type does not match the expected instance. Did you pass a reference from a different Firestore SDK?`

So I am thinking that using Firebase from my package creates separate Firebase SDK instance.

I use same firebase package version in my app and package, also set package firebase as peer dependency.

I was expecting to seamlessly use same `Firebase` object initialized in main app in my package.

Can someone help me understand if there is something I can do to realize this?

Here is code from my test package.

```
export class firestoreTest {
  private db: Firestore
  private app: FirebaseApp
  private dbFromApp: Firestore
  private localApp: FirebaseApp
  private localDb: Firestore

  constructor(firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions, app: FirebaseApp, db: Firestore) {
    this.db = db
    this.app = app

    this.dbFromApp = getFirestore(app)

    this.localApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    this.localDb = getFirestore(this.localApp)
  }

  public async getDoc(docPath: string, ref?: DocumentReference<DocumentData, DocumentData>) {
    /* Reads data, but without authenticated user context */
    /* Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. */
    // const data = await getDoc(doc(this.localDb, docPath).withConverter(converter<any>()))

    /* Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore */
    // const data = await getDoc(doc(this.dbFromApp, docPath).withConverter(converter<any>()))

    /* Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore */
    const data = await getDoc(doc(this.db, docPath).withConverter(converter<any>()))

    /* Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Type does not match the expected instance. Did you pass a reference from a different Firestore SDK? */
    // const data = ref && (await getDoc(ref.withConverter(converter<any>())))

    console.log(data?.data())
  }
}
```

UPDATE

I tried installing package from local source and using symlink to my local repo but that didn't help.

Then i pushed my package repo to GitHub and installing package with GitHub repo as source and now it works now.

Looks like when using local source, my package always uses separate instance of Firebase.
Putting entire package project folder inside my app folder and using package like part of app didn't help also.

Installing from GitHub is not a solution for development so I ended up creating folder in my app project where I put all my package files like part of my app. After I edit them I will copy to package repo.

Not sure if there is any better solution.

UPDATE

I found package `relative-deps` that solved my problem for development.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Original Poster answered his/her question via editing the question. Posting this for visibility of the community:

---

In `npm`, `relative-deps` refers to a feature that lets you define dependencies using relative file paths inside of a local package or workspace.

This functionality was added in `npm` version 7. You can directly reference other packages or modules within your project rather than relying on package names and the `npm` registry.

This makes development easier, especially for projects that use monorepos or numerous interrelated packages. In accordance with the file paths specified in the `package.json` file, `npm` resolves and installs the dependencies.

---

**Note**: *Only versions of npm begin with v7 and later support this capability.*